# MariaDB failed at step namespace spawning /bin/sh: read-only file system

Tags: centos7, mariadb

Recently my MariaDB stopped working and when I tried to start it, it always throws an error.

The error message is:

> MariaDB failed at step namespace spawning /bin/sh: read-only file system

What does that mean?

The operating system is CentOS 7

Comment: check the file system and see if a partition is mounted as `ro` rather than `rw`. Mostly that'll happen if there's an issue with the underlying storage, / will remount as ro etc.

Comment: @floodpants thank you, i will check when it happen again. will update the result here.

Comment: @floodpants yes indeed you are correct.the server changed the filesystem itself from rw to ro. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filesystem has likely been remounted as read only, which can indicate an issue with corruption or the underlying physical disk. You'll need to sort that and remount as rw then Maria should be ok to start again. Backup the db files asap also.